# Getting Previous Frontmost Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

Well, I’m stumped, here.  I’m writing a little utility that needs to know what the frontmost application was before my program starts.  I tried this:

```
var thePreviousApp:NSRunningApplication = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().frontmostApplication

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    thePreviousApp = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().frontmostApplication
}
```

It works when I run from Xcode (i.e. it sets thePreviousApp to “Xcode”) but when I run the binary from Finder or from Launchpad it returns the name of my program, not the program that was frontmost before my program started.

For what its worth, I can get the previous app by putting this in the AppDelegate:

```
var thePreviousApp:NSRunningApplication = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().frontmostApplication

 func applicationDidResignActive(notification: NSNotification!)
 {
    thePreviousApp = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().frontmostApplication
 }
```

If I start the program, then hit command-tab to activate the previous program, then hit command tab again to activate my program, thePreviousApp is the correct application.

I’ave also tried getting the array of runningApplications was NSWorkspace, then iterating through them to check which program is “active”.  Again, no dice.  Same problem.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

For those who are wondering, this is what I finally did.  I created a property in the AppDelegate called thePreviousApp.  Then created an observer object:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class theObserver: NSObject
{
    override init() {
        super.init()
        NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "setPreviousApplication:", name: NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func setPreviousApplication(notification: NSNotification!)
    {
        let theAppDelegate:AppDelegate=NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        theAppDelegate.thePreviousApp = notification.userInfo[NSWorkspaceApplicationKey] as NSRunningApplication
    }
}
```

This object is instantiated in the AppDelegate.

Thanks to MrAsterico for his help.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you should do something like this, but the only way I can think of is the one using the NSWorkspace notification (NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification).

You have to register one of your objects as an observer on that notification and then use the notification object to get the application that has been deactivated.

With your code, you always get your application, because frontmostApplication() is not updated at the exactly same moment when the applicationDidResignActive notification is raised.

Comment: Thanks.  I shouldn’t have been surprised.  Probably the order goes something like this:

1.  NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification fires

2.  applicationWillBecomeActive in my AppDelegate fires

3.  my application becomes active and frontmost

4.  applicationDidBecomeActive in my AppDelegate fires


So when I put the notification in applicationWillBecomeActive, there was no active application and therefore I got a return of nil.  Correct?

Comment: Anyway, it turns out that Swift doesn’t really have key-value observing yet.  You can set up something that works for your own properties very easily with the willSet and didSet functions.  But its not so easy for NSWorkspace notifications and such yet.

That’s OK.  Knowing its still developing, I chose to use Swift because this little project isn’t mission critical. I’m sure full KVO will be coming soon.

Comment: @TomS. KVO has nothing to do with the `NSWorkspace` notifications. `NSRunningApplication` only updates itself when the run loop runs. So there's no reason to expect it to be set up before the app has started.

Answer (score 1):

i found a way which gives the running Application-Windows in correct zPositions:

let windowNumbers = NSWindow.windowNumbersWithOptions( NSWindowNumberListAllSpaces | NSWindowNumberListAllApplications as NSWindowNumberListOptions )

it will return an array with the windowNumbers, and compared to CGWindowListCopyWindowInfos now they are in correct order Front to Back.

as they are only the windowIds you still need to make a Lookup in the CGWindowListCopyWindowInfos Array/Dictionary to get the Details.

But It works ! It will return more Windows than the obvious visible windows, but you can Filter them quite good with windowName != "" and other filters like size > 32x32 (to skip menubar)

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to read the windows-list which is ordered in recently used, I guess.
At least the zposition should be in order because the apps always get sorted to the front (order out front).
So your "last" app should be next to the list.

You would take the second program from the windowlist, as yours now is on top of the stack.
If you start without a gui, eg. all windows hidden, the last app might still be on top of the stack.
CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo gives you the list of all running apps, and even the hidden ones like notification center or the desktop-image and menubars.

update: list of runningApplications is in sort of random order and not in order of zPositions, so this idea does not work.